# Can you limit something to a state of complete reduction?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, american-english, semantics, pragmatics

If I were to limit something, does that mean I could limit it to a state of non-existence or none? Like if someone limits your abilities to talk can that entail that they prevent you from talking altogether? Does limit entail any reduction of whatever noun that comes after it or any reduction with the exception of a complete reduction.

Comment: Placing a "limit" on something means establishing a barrier beyond which it cannot go.  You can put a dog inside a fence and "limit" him to the fenced-in area, but he can still move around in that area.

Comment: @HotLicks but the question is in the context of your example, whether we can limit something to the point in which that dog cannot exist within the confines on the fenced in area. Or to a point in which that fenced in area doesn't exist because the limits are set to the smallest possible dimensions.

Comment: You can always make the fenced area so small that the dog does not comfortably fit inside it and is squashed to death.  Zero can be a "limit".

Comment: You are limited to posting zero questions from now on. Nah, not really. But yes, you can be limited to doing nothing, being nothing, etc. A limit is nothing more than a restriction. You can restrict the entire universe, resulting in the empty set. No problem.

Answer (score 2):

With quasi-real commodities such as money, zero amounts are possible. Thus a 'zero spending limit' is appliable.

According to [Adrian B at Advertisercommunity.com](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Billing/I-only-have-debit-cards-I-tried-to-fill-the-details-and-it-isn-t/td-p/169052#):

> Some banks configure the cards with a zero spending limit for internet
>   unsecure transactions.

One could likewise limit one's time abroad to zero, though one would usually choose a more idiomatic way to express this.

However, limiting real spaces, amounts of material etc will not always be feasible below certain finite – er – limits.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the definition of *limit* on Google:

> [*limit*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=limit&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):
>   a restriction on the size or amount of something permissible or
>   possible

If I were to put limits on your talking, at an all-day meeting I've organized, say, I could limit your talking to no more than one hour total, to no more than five minutes total, or to not talking at all -- because I just want you there to observe and take notes. One hour, five minutes, and no talking at all are perfectly fine limits. There is nothing about the definition of *limit* that rules out the "limiting case" of a complete prohibition.